# Kivy - Trying to integrate firebase with my kivy app? Json Error

Tags: python, json, firebase, python-requests, kivy

I have watched a few videos on using a firebase database with kivy and python to implement it with my app. However, I keep getting a 
`raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
 json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error. Please let me know if more code or information is needed.

Here is my code:

```
class MetropolisApp(App):
database_url = ''
user_num = 1

def build(self):
    return ControlScreens()

def on_start(self):
    # Get database data
    db = requests.get('' + str(self.user_num) + '.json')
    print(db.ok)
    data = json.loads(db.content.decode())
    print(data)

def patch(self, firstname, lastname, phonenumber, username, password):
    user_fname = json.loads(firstname)
    user_lname = json.loads(lastname)
    user_phone = json.loads(phonenumber)
    user_user = json.loads(username)
    user_pw = json.loads(password)
    requests.patch(url=self.database_url, json=user_fname)
    requests.patch(url=self.database_url, json=user_lname)
    requests.patch(url=self.database_url, json=user_phone)
    requests.patch(url=self.database_url, json=user_user)
    requests.patch(url=self.database_url, json=user_pw)
```

Comment: can you show what one of your variables like `firstname` or `phonenumber` looks like? Also it looks like you might mean to be using `requests.patch` to `self.database_url + str(self.user_num)` not just `self.database_url` in your `patch` function?

Comment: @Erik I have 0 knowledge of firebase so I might have messed up a lot. The parameters in the patch function are all ids from my .kv file textinputs. I'm trying to get the text and add it in my database.

Comment: So in the `patch` function, your `firstname` variable is just a simple string? like `'Bob'` or something?

Comment: @Erik you're talking about in my database? If so then yeah. fname: 'Test'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is `json.loads` is meant to convert a string like `'{"some_key": "some_value"}'` to a python dictionary like `{"some_key": "some_value"}`. You're trying to use `json.loads` on a string like `'Test'`, which produces your error.

What (I think) you mean to do is something like:

```
def patch(self, firstname, lastname, phonenumber, username, password):
    fname_data = {"fname": firstname} # Make a python dictionary
    requests.patch(url=self.database_url, json=fname_data) # Send the python dictionary
```

the `json` keyword argument of `requests.patch` expects a python dictionary.

Comment: is there a way for me to update `user_num` every time a user is created ? Like with a for loop or something.

Comment: You could have a field `next_user_num` in your database. Each time you create a new user, do a `requests.get(self.database_url + "next_user_num.json")`, then use what that returns. Then make sure you update it in the databse using a patch request.

Comment: Thanks @Erik. Do you have an example in the video series ?

Comment: I do, but it won't be released for a couple days. Keep trying it yourself for now, you can get it!

Comment: Will do. Thank you